# Moving hex data from a varchar type field to bigint type (mysql)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert data from one table into another, and each table has an 'id' field that should be the same, but is stored different datatype.  This 'id' field should represent the same unique value, allowing me to update from one to another.

In one table (the new.table one), the 'id' is stored as datatype `varchar(35)` and in the old.table it is datatype `bigint(20)` -- I believe this older table represents the integer version of the hex value stored in the new one. I am trying to update data from the new.table back into the old.table

After searching about this for a while

When I try this simple mysql update query it fails:

```
INSERT INTO old.table (id, field2)
    SELECT CAST(CONV(id,16,10) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER), field2
FROM new.table;
```

It fails with this error:

```
Out of range value for column 'id' at row 1
```

I have also tried a simple 
`SELECT CAST(CONV(id, 16,10) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) from new.table;`

And the result is all the same integer mostly, but each hex value in new.table is unique.   I've google this for two days, and could really use to help to figure out what is wrong. Thanks.

EDIT: Some of the example data from console of output of SELECT ID from new.table:

`| 1d2353560110956e1b3e8610a35d903a    |
| ec526762556c4f92a3ea4584a7cebfe1.11 |
| 34b8c838c18a4c5690514782b7137468.16 |
| 1233fa2813af44ca9f25bb8cac05b5b5.16 |
| 37f396d9c6e04313b153a34ab1e80304.16 |`

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Answer (score 0):

The problem `id` is too high values.

`MySQL` will return limit-value when overflow happened.

**Query 1**:

```
select CONV('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF1',16,10)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/beebfa/1/0)**:

```
| CONV('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF1',16,10) |
|---------------------------------|
|            18446744073709551615 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
select CONV('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF',16,10)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/62259/1)**:

```
| CONV('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF',16,10) |
|--------------------------------|
|           18446744073709551615 |
```

I would suggest you, Implement the logic algorithm for `id` in your case in a function instead of use `CONV` function.

**EDIT**

I would use a variable to make new row number and insert to `old` table.

```
CREATE TABLE new(
   Id varchar(35)
);

insert into new values ('1d2353560110956e1b3e8610a35d903a');
insert into new values ('ec526762556c4f92a3ea4584a7cebfe1.11');
insert into new values ('34b8c838c18a4c5690514782b7137468.16');
insert into new values ('1233fa2813af44ca9f25bb8cac05b5b5.16');
insert into new values ('37f396d9c6e04313b153a34ab1e80304.16');


CREATE TABLE old(
   Id bigint(20),
   val varchar(35)
);

INSERT INTO old (id, val)
    SELECT rn, id
FROM (
  SELECT *,(@Rn:=@Rn +1) rn
  FROM new CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Rn:=0) v 
) t1
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT * FROM old
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/beebfa/1/0)**:

```
| Id |                                 val |
|----|-------------------------------------|
|  1 |    1d2353560110956e1b3e8610a35d903a |
|  2 | ec526762556c4f92a3ea4584a7cebfe1.11 |
|  3 | 34b8c838c18a4c5690514782b7137468.16 |
|  4 | 1233fa2813af44ca9f25bb8cac05b5b5.16 |
|  5 | 37f396d9c6e04313b153a34ab1e80304.16 |
```

Comment: Can you show me an example of a logic algorithm to use a function to get these values into the BigInt format?